# Flavoring Packages

Tags: python, python-2.6

I use a package which has a structure somewhat similar to the following when communicating with a piece of hardware:

```
channel
   __init__.py
   transport
      __init__.py
      flow.py
      multiplex.py
   network
      __init__.py 
      header.py
      addressing.py
```

I now wish to be able to configure my package so that I can use it to communicate with two very similar hardwares. For example, when communicating with hw1 I want the equivalent of the following in adressing.py:

```
from collections import namedtuple
PacketSize = namedtuple('PacketSize', ('header', 'body'))
packet_size = PacketSize(16,256)
```

while when testing hw2, I want the equivalent of:

```
from collections import namedtuple
PacketSize = namedtuple('PacketSize', ('header', 'body'))
packet_size = PacketSize(8,256)
```

Almost all of the modules in the packages are the same for both hw1 and hw2. I might however even have slightly different flavours for certain functions and classes within the package.

I was thinking I could solve this by having this structure:

```
channel
   __init__.py
   transport
      __init__.py
      flow.py
      multiplex.py
   network
      __init__.py 
      header.py
      addressing.py
      hw1
         __init__.py 
         addressing.py
      hw2    
         __init__.py 
         addressing.py
```

So each subpackage will contain a hw1 and hw2 subpackage where hardware specific code is placed. I have programmed channel/network/addressing.py as follows:

```
from collections import namedtuple
PacketSize = namedtuple('PacketSize', ('header', 'body'))
if hardware == "hw1":
   from hw1.targetprops import * 
elif hardware == "hw2":
   from hw2.targetprops import *
```

And channel/network/hw1/addressing.py like this:

```
from ..addressing import PacketSize
packet_size = PacketSize(16,256)
```

Does this make sense? I think channel/network/addressing.py is ugly to be honest since I'm doing an import, then I define a namedtuple, then I continue with the conditional imports. Could I do this better?

Is the general approach above the best way to flavor a package?

Is there a standard way to configure the package so that it knows if it is concerned with hw1 or hw2? At the moment I just have a global called hardware as seen above when I do `if harware == "hw1"`.

Comment: About defining PacketSize first and then doing conditional imports: I don't find it that ugly as the imports are still quite at the top, but then again I see nothing in your code example that would prevent you doing the conditional imports first as usual and then define PacketSize. Unless you have a circular import, and hw1.targetprops imports channel.network.addressing. That would be a bit ugly and error prone, and then you should put the PacketSize definition in a different module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to abstract away the hardware/flavor dependent features behind some kind of common interface. There are many different ways to do this, such as class inheritance, [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), passing around an object, or --- as you may be looking to do --- even as a global python module or object.

I personally tend to often favor composition, because class inheritance often isn't a natural fit, and may blow up into multiple inheritance or `MixInMadness`.

A global Python module (or a sigleton object) is attractive, but I would steer away unless there really, really has to be only one of them in a single process. Good examples where this is a good design is when it is tied to the underlying platform, for instance the Python `os` module that has much the same interface on Windows and Linux but works very differently underneath. Compare this to your `hw1` and `hw2`. Another good example is the Twisted reactor, of which there really can only be one running at a time. Even then, a large part of the Twisted code passes around a `reactor` object for e.g., compositing. This is partly to make unit testing possible.

For your example, if hw1 or hw2 refers to the hardware your program is running on, then a global python module does make sense. If it instead refers to hardware your program is communicating with, e.g., over a serial port or the network, then a global module is the wrong approach. You might have have two serial ports and want to speak to hw1 and hw2 in the same process.

For an example on how to use a global module, or actually a global object, I recommend looking at [how Twisted does it](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-14.0.2/twisted/internet/main.py). Then your modules would do something like

```
from mypackage import hardware # hw1/hw2 automatically detected

print hardware.packet_size # different for different hardware
```

or

```
# main.py
from mypackage import hw1
hw1.init()

# other.py
from mypackage import hardware # initialized to hw1 in main.py
```

Compositing or passing around an object on the other hand would look something like:

```
hw = mypackage.hw1.hw1factory()
send_data(hw, 'foo') # uses hw.packet_size

hw = mypackage.hw2.hw2factory()
frob = Frobnicator(hw)
frob.frobnicate('foo') # uses hw.packet_size internally
```

Comment: With regard to you first two coded examples above, isn't this exactly what I'm doing? Would you have any suggestions on how I might improve channel/network/addressing.py and channel/network/hw1/addressing.py examples referred to in my question. Thanks!

Comment: You are correct that the examples use a technique similar to what you are doing. I still think that it is often better to use classes and objects to keep parameters and state instead of global singleton variables or modules. I recommend looking at Twisted for a well thought out approach to "configure" a package (twisted.internet.reactor) as you asked about.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong.  You should not have multiple modules to distinguish cases.  In the case you describe, the module color.py might contain a function to which you pass a list of items to be tested and colors to test the items with.  How you organize this depends on the data source and destination and the nature of the items you are testing.

Comment: I've changed my example to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [py.test](http://pytest.org) and fixtures (which are NOT like Django fixtures). These do exactly what you want and `py.test` can handle `UnitTest` and `Nose` style tests as well.

Comment: I've changed my example to eliminate confusion.